# How to identify file name that has parsing error in Python?

Tags: python

I have over 100 csv files and am trying to combine them to a single file, but a file, say "x.csv" has a row "y" that is a bad row. This caused ParseError: Error tokenizing data when I am combining them. Is a there a command to identify the file name and the row of the bad line without me having to go through files to identify which csv and which line is bad ?

edit: below is the code I have right now, I am getting a NameError: name 'f' is not defined

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.parsers import ParserError
import os
folder_path=  'input_folder'
txt_files = os.listdir(folder_path)

try:
    combined_csv = pd.concat( [ pd.read_csv(f, sep = '|', warn_bad_lines=True) for f in txt_files] )
except ParserError:
    print("Parsing error for:", f)
```

Comment: We need a bit more information to answer this question. Could you share the code you use to open the file and combine them? It is impossible to answer without knowing what libraries you are using to open the file.

Comment: added in the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to catch the file using the following `try` & `except` blocks:

```
try:
    #your code to open files and parse their contents
    #...
    #...
except ParseError:
    print("Parsing error for: ", filename)
```

This would print out the problematic file.

**EDIT**

For your particular example, I would go along these lines:

```
df_list = []

for f in txt_files:
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(f, sep = '|', warn_bad_lines=True)
        df_list.append(df)
    except ParserError:
        print("Parsing error for:", f)  

combined_csv = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Comment: thanks, I have tried this but I am getting NameError: name 'f' is not defined, my code is in the post

Comment: @user12229564 Using a list comprehension will not allow for except to access the object.

Comment: How can i overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you're parsing the csvs, but based on the error I'm assuming you're using pandas.read_csv() and also that you want to read the usable portion of the file instead of just moving on to the next file. If that's the case, use the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True)
```

And look at [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to see what your other options are. This will communicate the full error and its location in the file. As far as identifying the file itself, you could either redirect stdout and add the filename to warnings or just output the filenames before attempting to read the file.